How to write custom logs from DbContext method
I have a custom method in DbContext and I want to write some extra logs from it:
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
   public async Task CustomBulkInsert(...)
   {
       //how to write logs from here?
   }
}

I don't want to inject my own ILogger since DbContext already has logging built it.

If you are adding context via standard methods like AddDbContext/AddDbContextFactory then you can just inject logger into the constructor:
public class ExampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly ILogger<ExampleDbContext> _logger;

    public ExampleDbContext(DbContextOptions<ExampleDbContext> o
        , ILogger<ExampleDbContext>? logger) : base(o)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task CustomBulkInsert(...)
    {
        _logger?.LogInformation("Doing work CONTEXT CUSTOM");
        // ...
    }

}

Alternatively if you really-really want you can use the internal EF Core API (I would recommend against this but still):
public async Task CustomBulkInsert(...)
{
    this.GetDependencies().UpdateLogger.Logger.LogInformation("Doing work CONTEXT CUSTOM");
    // ...
}


The this.GetDependencies().UpdateLogger.Logger does not write any logs when using optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine)

@Liero it did when I tested in my setup, but without seeing yours - it is hard to tell what is the caveat here.

You can access the same ILogger that DbContext uses internally.
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public async Task CustomBulkInsert(...)    
    {
        var logger = this.GetService<ILogger<MyDbContext>>(); 

        logger.LogInformation("Starting custom bulk insert operation...");

        // ... your bulk insert logic ...

        logger.LogInformation("Custom bulk insert operation completed.");

    }
}


Where did you find DbContext.GetService ? There's no such member or extension method in DbContext

It is a protected method, but it return null.

@PanagiotisKanavos it is from AccessorExtensions.GetService I would guess that it is similar to var requiredService = this.GetInfrastructure().GetService<ILogger<ExampleDbContext>>();

Using infrastructure methods is .... fragile
